# OpenGL: Flipping an Item

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, translation, flip

I've created a "Polyman" and a "Polywoman". The polyman walks from the right to the middle of the screen while the polywoman walks from the left to the middle of the screen.

I used all the same points for polyman and polywoman including the feet, meaning polywoman's feet are pointed in the wrong direction, is there a way I can simply flip polywoman 180% on the z axis to make her feet point in the right direction, or am I doomed to create her own feet?

I know creating new feet wouldn't take very long, but gaining the knowledge of how to flip an icon will greatly further my abilities in future assignments.

Comment: Show some code, especially how you draw the woman. But in general: Yes it is in OpenGL absolutely possible to flip something (since this is just a scaling by -1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (from your title) that you're working with raw OpenGL, just use a different model matrix when drawing PolyWoman that scales her in the x direction with a factor of -1;

Comment: no way it's that simple? I forget, is it best to translate, rotate, then scale? or translate, scale, then rotate?

Comment: Do you mean when placing an object in world space? If I remember correctly: first scale, then rotate, then translate. But I suggest you try it and change it if it doesn't work. Remember that if you want to represent those transformations as matrices and combine them into a single matrix by multiplying them the order of multiplication is reversed. So `modelMatrix = translateMat * rotateMat * scaleMat` will first scale, then rotate and then translate.